# SSL not working with subdomains

Tags: nginx, ssl, http

I have an issue here, I am new on this, I've been watching some tutorials and I see that everything is OK in my configuration but I can not access to my page with the subdomains.

[Here is the report of my SSL domain from SSL LABS](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=just4bettors.mobi)

and here I have the config file

this is the one for the domain

```
#////////MOBILE//////    
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name just4bettors.mobi;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name just4bettors.mobi;
  include ssl.conf;
  root   /home/c0pt/capilleira/capilleiraclickandgamblemobile/www;
  location / {
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }
  include protect_system_files.conf;
  include expires.conf;
}
```

and then in a separate block I have 2 subdomains

```
#//////BACK END//////
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name backend.just4bettors.mobi;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name backend.just4bettors.mobi;
  include ssl.conf;
  location / {
    include security.conf;
    include backend_proxy_pass.conf;
  }
  include protect_system_files.conf;
}


#////////DESKTOP//////
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name desktop.just4bettors.mobi;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name desktop.just4bettors.mobi;
  include ssl.conf;
  root   /home/c0pt/capilleira/capilleiraclickandgambleweb/dist;
  location / {
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }
  include protect_system_files.conf;
  include expires.conf;
}
```

as you see I have the backend in a subdomain. At this moment I can see the domain just4bettors.mobi, but once I attempt to enter, I receive an error `OPTIONS http://localhost:1337/auth/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, Look that I have the domain aiming to the backend subdomain, and if I attempt to enter to the desktop.just4bettors.mobi subdomain I get this in the browser `This webpage is not available` and this in the browser console `GET https://desktop.just4bettors.mobi/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

so, what am I missing here ?

Comment: Good job on your A+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The desktop subdomain doesnt seem to be setup in DNS.  Nor is backend.

You need to set A records for those subdomains in your DNS, which appears to be ultradns.net